# Sizes of the original ESP32-DevKitC-32U Wifi board

Tags: esp32, pcb-design

I know that this topic does not apply to Arduino, but for me it is important to find a solution to the problem. I know the consequences.

I'm creating a pcb board into which the original ESP32-DevKitC-32U module will be inserted. I can not find the original dimensions of the board, in particular the distance between the contact rails. The site espressif has a small description.

[image]

27.9mm is indicated here. It is not clear to me, is this the full width of the board or the distance between the contacts?

What I want to do:

[image]
[image]

It is very important for me to find out the correct dimensions of the original board. Maybe someone has such a board and can measure this size?

Answer (score 2):

The distance of the headers is breadboard and perfboard compatible for 0.1" (2.54 mm) pin standard. 25.4 mm is 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am taking a class and the instructor used a DEVKITC V4, which on a standard breadboard, plugged into columns b and i.  The DEVKITC that I ordered from Mouser plugs into columns b and j.  So one is a pin-to pin width of 25.4 mm and the other is 27.9 mm.  It seems that the newer DEVKITC V4 is 27.9 and is very difficult to work with on standard breadboard.  PITA!